# Run the code When all Threads are done (Python ThreadPoolExecutor)

Tags: multithreading

I want to find a way to run a code when all Threads are done using ThreadPoolExecutor.

Here is a slice of my code (Making GUI with Tkinter).
I want to config the label when all threads are done.

How can I achieve this?

```
def logic(labels):
    length = len(files)
    global datalist
    global future1
    global future2
    global future3
    datalist = []
    for i in range(length):
        name = files[i]
        ext = name.split('.')[-1]
        file_name = os.path.basename(name)
        if file_name.startswith('!v3'):
            raw_data = pd.read_excel(name, sheet_name=None)
            raw_data = pd.concat(raw_data,ignore_index=True)
        elif (ext == 'xlsx') or (ext == 'xls'):
            raw_data = pd.read_excel(name)
        else:
            raw_data = pd.read_csv(name, encoding='CP949')
        file_name = os.path.basename(name)
        if file_name.startswith('!v1'):
            raw_data['업장명'] = file_name.split('_')[1]
            with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
                future1 = executor.submit(data_processing1, raw_data)
                final1 = future1.result()
                datalist.append(final1)
            
        elif file_name.startswith('!v2'):
            if '지점명' not in raw_data.columns :
                raw_data['지점명'] = file_name.split('_')[2]
            raw_data['업장명'] = file_name.split('_')[1]
            with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
                future2 = executor.submit(data_processing2, raw_data)
                final2 = future2.result()
                datalist.append(final2)
        
        elif file_name.startswith('!v3'):
            raw_data['업장명']=file_name.split('_')[1]
            with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
                future3 = executor.submit(data_processing3, raw_data)
                final3 = future3.result()
                datalist.append(final3)
            
        else:
            space()
            label = Label(root, text = name + '파일 이름 에러')
            label.pack()
            
        labels.config(text='Complete')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to config the label when all threads are done.
>
> How can I solve this?

You can do it with [`concurrent.futures.wait`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.wait) - here's a sketch based on your code:

```
def logic(labels):
    length = len(files)
    global datalist
    datalist = []
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(length) as executor:
        fs = [] # list of the Future instances created
        for i in range(length):
            …
            if file_name.startswith('!v1'):
                raw_data['업장명'] = file_name.split('_')[1]
                fs.append(executor.submit(data_processing1, raw_data))
            elif file_name.startswith('!v2'):
                if '지점명' not in raw_data.columns:
                    raw_data['지점명'] = file_name.split('_')[2]
                raw_data['업장명'] = file_name.split('_')[1]
                fs.append(executor.submit(data_processing2, raw_data))
            elif file_name.startswith('!v3'):
                raw_data['업장명'] = file_name.split('_')[1]
                fs.append(executor.submit(data_processing3, raw_data))
            else:
                …
        concurrent.futures.wait(fs) # wait for all threads
        for f in fs: datalist.append(f.result())
    labels.config(text='Complete')
```

Note that although you could do it with multiple Executor instances, I used only one.